# Redux Dynamic Modules: Type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to type 'Action'

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-dynamic-modules

I'm implementing `redux-dynamic-modules` in my application and it is not the first module in my app, but I get strange error when I try to create this module:

```
export const reduxProfile = () => {
  return {
    id: 'profile',
    reducerMap: {
      profile: reducer
    },
    sagas: [profileSagas],
    retained: true
  }
}
```

> ```
>           Type 'Reducer<ProfileState, Action>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<any, AnyAction>'.
>             Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
>               Type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
>                 Type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to type 'SetPriceAction'.
> ```

And here's my `SetPriceAction` which seems to look just fine:

```
export interface SetPriceAction extends AnyAction {
  payload: Result;
  type: ActionTypes.SET_PRICE;
}
...
export type Action =
  | ...
  | SetPriceAction;
```

In another module is pretty much of the same shape, and everything works fine there.
Can anybody help what went wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

A quick bypass would be to set your payload as optional.

```
export interface SetPriceAction extends AnyAction {
  payload?: Result;
  type: ActionTypes.SET_PRICE;
}
```

But I am actively looking for a long term solution requiring the payload to be defined. I'll let you know if I make any progress on the matter

Comment: Any luck on finding a longer-term solution? Over two years later? :-)